# ¿Cómo exportar una fila de un DataGridView a un archivo txt?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

¿Cómo puedo seleccionar una fila de un DataGridView y exportarla a un archivo .txt que tenga el nombre de una columna del DataGridView?

Por el momento tengo un botón para exportar todo los datos del gridview a un .txt aquí esta el código:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
            if (!Directory.Exists(@"D:\Carpeta"))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(@"D:\Carpeta");
            }

            TextWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"D:\Carpeta\Archivo.txt");
            int rowcount = TablaDatos.Rows.Count;
            for(int i = 0; i < rowcount -1; i++)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(TablaDatos.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString()+"\t"
                             +TablaDatos.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString()+"\t"
                              +TablaDatos.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString()+"\t"
                               +TablaDatos.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString()+"\t");
            }
            sw.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Datos Exportados correctamente");    
        }
```

Necesito exportar fila por fila creando un txt por cada fila y no todo el DataGridView

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @AbregoW, por favor añade mas detalles a tu pregunta, es winforms o asp.net? Pon un ejemplo de salida de tu archivo, etc...

Comment: Hola, así como dice @CarlosMuñoz, agrega todos los datos que puedas, eso ayudará a que te ayudemos, bendiciones :)

Comment: Listo compañeros ya lo edite, eso tengo en el botón para exportar

Comment: entonces es un desarrollo web ? digo porque el GridView es de asp.net mientras que el DataGridView es winforms

Comment: No no es desarrollo Web, es aplicacion de escritorio, es Windows Forms

Answer (score 2):

Lo que recomendaría es que no exportes desde un control sino que vuelques los datos a una clase para luego usar una librería como ser

[filehelpers](http://www.filehelpers.net/)

Entonces creas una clase

```
[DelimitedRecord("\t")]
public class Item
{

    public string Prop1 {get;set;}
    public string Prop2 {get;set;}
    public string Prop3 {get;set;}
}
```

y exportas volcando los datos a esa clase

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    List<Item> Items = new List<Item>();

    foreach(var row in DataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        Item _item = new Item()
        {
            Prop1 = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString(),
            Prop2 = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString(),
            Prop3 = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString(),
        };
        Items.Add(_item);
    }

    var engine = new FileHelperEngine<Item>();
    engine.WriteFile(@"D:\Carpeta\Archivo.txt", Items);

    MessageBox.Show("Datos Exportados correctamente");    
}
```

notaras que la clase define el atributo `[DelimitedRecord("\t")]` indicando cual es el separador

Comment: Hola @AbregoW si esta o cualquier otra respuesta ha resuelto su problema, por favor considera [aceptarla](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) clicando la marca de check (en forma de V debajo de la puntuación de la respuesta). Esto indica a la comunidad que has encontrado una solución y de paso os dará reputación a ambos (a tí y quien ha respondido). Por supuesto, no tienes ninguna obligación de hacerlo.

Answer (score 1):

Para exportar una fila de un DataGridView basándonos en tu algoritmo ya creado. Le he hecho algunas modificaciones, como cambiar el ciclo `for` de tu algoritmo por un `foreach`, para que pudieras iterar sobre cada fila y del DataGridView y retornar la fila como objeto. También hice uso del método `Combine()` de la clase `Path` que se encuentra en el espacio de nombre `System.IO` para poder combinar las cadenas de texto para crear una dirección al fichero *.txt* que crearás.

Al haber cerrado el TextWriter fuera del ciclo, todo el texto que se almacenó en el buffer ha sido escrito en el mismo archivo. Para eso he puesto las partes de `sw = new StreamWriter(...)` y `sw.Close()` dentro del ciclo, para que cada vez que se itere el ciclo se escriba el texto en un documento diferente.

Así que para exportar una fila de un DataGridView basándonos en tu algoritmo ya creado, propongo el siguiente código:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        if (!Directory.Exists(@"D:\Carpeta"))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(@"D:\Carpeta");
        }

        TextWriter sw;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow x in TablaDatos.Rows)
        {
            int i = x.Index;
            sw = new StreamWriter(System.IO.Path.Combine("D:\Carpeta\", ("Archivo" + i.ToString() + ".txt"));

            sw.WriteLine(x.Cells[0].Value.ToString()+"\t"
                         +x.Cells[1].Value.ToString()+"\t"
                          +x.Cells[2].Value.ToString()+"\t"
                           +x.Cells[3].Value.ToString()+"\t");
            sw.Close();
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Datos Exportados correctamente");    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

En realidad para exportar cada fila a un archivo diferente no tienes más que meter la creación y el cierre del TextWriter dentro del bucle for, asignándole un nombre diferente en cada iteración al fichero:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(@"D:\Carpeta"))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(@"D:\Carpeta");
        }

        int rowcount = TablaDatos.Rows.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < rowcount - 1; i++)
        {
            TextWriter sw = new StreamWriter($@"D:\Carpeta\Archivo_{i}.txt");
            sw.WriteLine(TablaDatos.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "\t"
                         + TablaDatos.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "\t"
                          + TablaDatos.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString() + "\t"
                           + TablaDatos.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString() + "\t");
            sw.Close();
        }
        MessageBox.Show(@"Datos Exportados correctamente");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No veo que nadie esté respondiendo directamente a tu pregunta. Añade un nuevo botón al Form y haz algo similar a esto:

```
private void btnExportSelectedRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Nos aseguramos de que haya al menos un row seleccionado
    if (TablaDatos.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
    {
        DataGridViewRow selectedRow = TablaDatos.SelectedRows[0];                

        // Obtenemos el nombre del fichero en función del número de fila seleccionado       
        string fileName = "Archivo" + selectedRow.Index + ".txt";

        using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(@"D:\Carpeta", fileName)))
        {
            // Unimos todos los valores del row que no sean nulos en un string
            string output = string.Join("\t", selectedRow.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
                                                               .Where(c => c.Value != null)
                                                               .Select(c => c.Value.ToString())
                                                               .ToArray());
            writer.WriteLine(output);
        }
    }
}
```

Ten en cuenta que para que el ejemplo anterior funcione debe estar seleccionado el row y no sólo una celda. Si quieres obtener la información de la fila a partir de la celda seleccionada, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
int rowIndex = TablaDatos.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
DataGridViewRow selectedRow = TablaDatos.Rows[rowIndex];
```