# Exportar datagridview a Excel

Tags: vb.net

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

-Me sale este error al abrir la exportacion del datagrid a excel, sera necesario una libreria para corregir este error?

Necesito exportar un datagrid que me trae una consulta Select con 251 filas a Excel, tengo un codigo para hacerlo pero sucede que cuando son muchas filas, el programa se detiene :

```vb
Public Function GridAExcel(ByVal ElGrid As DataGridView) As Boolean
        ''Creamos las variables
        Dim exApp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        Dim exLibro As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
        Dim exHoja As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
        Try
            ''Añadimos el Libro al programa, y la hoja al libro
            exLibro = exApp.Workbooks.Add
            exHoja = exLibro.Worksheets.Add
            '' ¿Cuantas columnas y cuantas filas?
            Dim NCol As Integer = ElGrid.ColumnCount
            Dim NRow As Integer = ElGrid.RowCount
            ''Aqui recorremos todas las filas, y por cada fila todas las columnas y vamos escribiendo.
            For i As Integer = 1 To NCol
                exHoja.Cells.Item(1, i) = ElGrid.Columns(i - 1).Name.ToString 
End Function
```

---

Este es el error que me sale, no se que pueda ser la verdad, ya importe en el formulario y en la clase la librería.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es una aplicación Web o una aplicación de Escritorio?

Comment: Aplicacion de Escritorio

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en español. Deberías postear el código que tienes para poder saber que es lo que va mal y ayudarte. Lee [como crear un ejemplo mínimo verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y [como preguntar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: porque usas las librerias de excel? eso es terriblemente lento

Comment: fue lo mas sencillo que encontre en internet, que librerias me recomiendas??

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio @JoseEmilianoPaz. Por favor utiliza la sección de respuestas para publicar **respuestas** a tu pregunta. Si necesitas agregar información a tu pregunta, por favor **edítala** convenientemente para mostrar tu nueva situación. Por favor no edites la pregunta para agregar nuevas preguntas en base a tu pregunta, solo para agergar información para comprender mejor el problema.

Comment: Que penas, apenas me estoy acoplando con la plataforma

Answer (score 2):

Es fácil, solo tienes que dejar el formato que se vaya a guardar el código que debe ser en formato *.xlsx.

Te envio el código que utilizo.

```
'Exportar Data Grid de 1 a 3 dias
Private Sub btnImprimirde1a3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnImprimirde1a3.Click
    Try
        If ((dgv1a3.Columns.Count = 0) Or (dgv1a3.Rows.Count = 0)) Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'Creando Dataset para Exportar
        Dim dset As New DataSet
        'Agregar tabla al Dataset
        dset.Tables.Add()
        'AGregar Columna a la tabla
        For i As Integer = 0 To dgv1a3.ColumnCount - 1
            dset.Tables(0).Columns.Add(dgv1a3.Columns(i).HeaderText)
        Next
        'Agregar filas a la tabla
        Dim dr1 As DataRow
        For i As Integer = 0 To dgv1a3.RowCount - 1
            dr1 = dset.Tables(0).NewRow
            For j As Integer = 0 To dgv1a3.Columns.Count - 1
                dr1(j) = dgv1a3.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value
            Next
            dset.Tables(0).Rows.Add(dr1)
        Next

        Dim aplicacion As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass
        Dim wBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
        Dim wSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet

        wBook = aplicacion.Workbooks.Add()
        wSheet = wBook.ActiveSheet()

        Dim dt As System.Data.DataTable = dset.Tables(0)
        Dim dc As System.Data.DataColumn
        Dim dr As System.Data.DataRow
        Dim colIndex As Integer = 0
        Dim rowIndex As Integer = 0

        For Each dc In dt.Columns
            colIndex = colIndex + 1
            aplicacion.Cells(1, colIndex) = dc.ColumnName
        Next

        For Each dr In dt.Rows
            rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
            colIndex = 0
            For Each dc In dt.Columns
                colIndex = colIndex + 1
                aplicacion.Cells(rowIndex + 1, colIndex) = dr(dc.ColumnName)

            Next
        Next
        'Configurar la orientacion de la  hoja y el tamaño
        wSheet.PageSetup.Orientation = Excel.XlPageOrientation.xlLandscape
        wSheet.PageSetup.PaperSize = Excel.XlPaperSize.xlPaperLegal
        'Configurar con negrilla la cabecera y tenga autofit
        wSheet.Rows.Item(1).Font.Bold = 1
        wSheet.Columns.AutoFit()


        Dim strFileName As String = "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Escritorio\Reporte de 1 a 3 dias.xlsx"
        Dim blnFileOpen As Boolean = False
        Try
            Dim fileTemp As System.IO.FileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(strFileName)
            fileTemp.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            blnFileOpen = False
        End Try

        If System.IO.File.Exists(strFileName) Then
            System.IO.File.Delete(strFileName)
        End If
        MessageBox.Show("El documento fue exportado correctamente.", "Mensaje", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
        wBook.SaveAs(strFileName)
        aplicacion.Workbooks.Open(strFileName)
        aplicacion.Visible = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "SISTEMA INTEGRADO DE ADMINISTRACION DE PERSONAL", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Recomendaria lo mismo que aconseje en esta pregunta

[Como exportar una fila de un DataGridView a un archivo txt](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/4588/como-exportar-una-fila-de-un-datagridview-a-un-archivo-txt/4594#4594)

No exportes desde un control sino que vuelques los datos a una clase para luego usar una librería como ser

[filehelpers](http://www.filehelpers.net/)

Entonces creas una clase

```
<DelimitedRecord(vbTab)> _
Public class Item

    Public Property Prop1 As String
    Public Property Prop2 As String
    Public Property Prop3 As String

End Class
```

y exportas volcando los datos a esa clase

```
Private Sub button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim Items As New List(Of Item)

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows

        Dim _item As New Item() With { _
            .Prop1 = row.Cells(0).Value.ToString(), _
            .Prop2 = row.Cells(1).Value.ToString(), _
            .Prop3 = row.Cells(2).Value.ToString() _
        }

        Items.Add(_item)
    Next

    Dim engine = New FileHelperEngine(Of Item)
    engine.WriteFile("D:\Carpeta\Archivo.txt", Items.ToArray())

    MessageBox.Show("Datos Exportados correctamente")
End Sub
```

De esta forma no exportas del grid directo al archivo sino que usas una clase intermedia.

Recuerda declarar el `Imports` a `System.Collections.Generic` para que reconozca por ejemplo el metodo `ToArray()`

Comment: Me perdi en el codigo: por que solo esta capturando 3 filas del datagridview??

Comment: y como hago para incluir esa libreria en el proyecto

Comment: Te dejo el codigo que estoy realizando la exportacion en este momento:

Comment: los de las 3 filas es solo un ejemplo, en tu caso crearias la clase con tantas propiedades como columnas tengas en el grid

Comment: podrias incluirla usando nuget  https://www.nuget.org/packages/FileHelpers/

Comment: Mi conocimiento sobre librerias es muy poco, la descargo y que debo hacer??

Comment: Primero podrias leer y ver los ejemplos de la documentacion de la libreria, sino lo haces es seguro que conoceras como trabajar con los metodos que expone. Despues podrias ver el ejemplo que propuse, si bien es algo basico podria dar una pista donde comenzar

Comment: la variable var donde la declaro?

Comment: disculpa fue un error de la coversion desde c# en tu caso seria            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows

Comment: Dim _item As New Item() With { _
            Key .Prop1 = row.Cells(0).Value.ToString(), _
            Key .Prop2 = row.Cells(1).Value.ToString(), _
            Key .Prop3 = row.Cells(2).Value.ToString() _
        }
            Items.Add(_item)
        Next

Comment: Tengo un error en el ciclo, en el 1er with key, yo creo que se te fue algo de c#

Comment: puede que el Key este demas, pero edito el codigo y realizo un codigo mas simple

Comment: Si le quito el key, de todas maneras me sigue saliendo error en esa misma linea de codigo

Comment: @JoseEmilianoPaz edite el codigo, analiza si el ToArray() resuelve el problema

Comment: El ToArray efectivamente resolvio el problema, pero ahora no me deja crear el archivo, me dice que la direccion no existe, me preocupa este punto por que al parecer la direccion debe ser predeterminada, me gustaria que la funcion creara el excel y ya despues de creado el usuario le pueda dar la ubicacion que el desee.

Comment: la direccion no existe ? no sera el path donde debe grabar el archivo. Podrias generarlo en memoria usando Dim stream As New MemoryStream()
Dim streamWriter As New StreamWriter(stream)
engine.WriteStream(streamWriter, records)  luego cuando tengas la ruta persistes alli

Comment: ya por fin me visualizo el excel pero con varias imperfecciones, el otro codigo me parece mas facil de manejar, lo unico malo es que despues de ciertas cantidad de registros se queda estatico, en la nueva implementacion x lo menos cuando le doy xlsx que es la extencion para excel crea el archivo pero no lo deja visualizar

Comment: como hago o que modificacion debo realizar para que yo no le de la ubicacion, si no que al usuario le salga la ventana de examinar y sea el mismo el que le de ubicacion

Comment: en realidad el pedido de la ubicacion deberias realizarlo previo a la generacion de la exportacion, asi al tener la ruta podrias generarlo directamente, podrias usar el OpenFileDialog https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: y como seria para que cuando finalice la exportacion, automaticamente se abra el excel con la informacion??

Comment: y como seria para que cuando finalice la exportacion, automaticamente se abra el excel con la informacion??

Comment: podrias usar el Process.Start() para lanzar el archivo con la aplicacion por defecto asociada a la extension

Comment: y que debo colocar en el parentesis del proccess.Star()     process.Star(engine)?????

Comment: la ruta del archivo que quieres que se abra, si la extension de este tiene un programa asociado lo abrira. El parametro es un string para lanzar un archivo

Comment: Leandro ya hice el savedialog y me manda a la ruta que yo le indique por defecto, pero ahora al abrir la exportacion a excel me sale el mensaje de la imagen, debo incluir una libreria de office para corregir esto, si le doy aceptar abre el excel normal, pero es un poco incomodo que al usuario le salga esta ventana.

Comment: Probe cambiandole la extencion de .xls a .xlsx pero me sale un error distinto y ni siquiera lo deja abrir

Comment: si vas a exportar separando con comas no lo cambies a xlsx proque no aplica, es mas deberias usar .csv

Comment: Con comas o sin comas sigue saliendo el error, y por  que .csv?

Comment: le coloque .csv y lo que me crea es un archivo de valores separados por comas de microsoft excel

Comment: exacto, estas creando mediente FileHelper un archivo separado por comas, excel lo reconoce porque cada valor seria una columna  https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSV, pero puedes abrirlo con el notepad si es que asocias esa extension

Comment: la verdad no gusta que quede asi, no hay otra forma de que el archivo de excel quede normal?? no hay una forma que sea similar al datagriaexcel que funciona con librerias de excel o una forma de acelerar ese proceso para  que no sea tan demorado??

Comment: la verdad no gusta que quede asi, no hay otra forma de que el archivo de excel quede normal?? no hay una forma que sea similar al datagriaexcel que funciona con librerias de excel o una forma de acelerar ese proceso para que no sea tan demorado??

Answer (score 0):

Inténtalo con el siguiente código:

```
   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application XcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                XcelApp.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);

                for (int i = 1; i < this.DataGridview.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
                {
                    XcelApp.Cells[1, i] = this.DataGridview.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
                }


                for (int i = 0; i < this.DataGridview.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < this.DataGridview.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        XcelApp.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = (this.DataGridview.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value != null) ? this.DataGridview.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString() : String.Empty;
                    }
                }
                XcelApp.Columns.AutoFit();
                XcelApp.Visible = true;
```

Únicamente cambia a la referencia a tu Grid ;)

¡Mucha Suerte! :D

Comment: Este funciona, pero lo que pasa es que cuando hay muchos registros se demora demasiado la exportacion (de 4 a 5 minutos)

Answer (score 0):

Te planteo una solución que a mi me sirvió y bastante tomando que he necesitado exportar más de 20,000 registros a un Excel y he querido priorizar como tu dices la velocidad.

Utilizar la librería **EPPlus**, que permite trabajar con Excel.

Lo que necesitamos es cargar los datos que vamos a exportar a un **DataTable** en memoria. Luego abrimos un código y facilmente lo llenamos con una sola sentencia.

1. Descargamos la librería de EPPlus: http://epplus.codeplex.com/
2. La agregamos a la referencia de nuestro proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3. Creamos el código (en mi caso cree un DataTable en Memoria y lo cargué).

   ```
       Dim DataTablePrueba As New DataTable
       DataTablePrueba.Columns.Add("N1")
       DataTablePrueba.Columns.Add("N2")
       For x = 0 To 30000
           DataTablePrueba.Rows.Add(x, x)
       Next
       Dim fileg As New FileInfo("C:\exportacion\export.xlsx")
       Using package As New ExcelPackage(fileg)
           Dim ws As ExcelWorksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Hoja1")
           ws.Cells("A1").LoadFromDataTable(DataTablePrueba, True)
           package.Save()
       End Using
   ```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

4. Y si tenemos en cuenta que el directorio de salida que pusimos existe, deberiamos ya tener el excel:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]